# phpMyAdmin cannot login - keeps asking for credentials

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin on my Arch linux box, it is running, so is apache with php and mysql.

When I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`, it shows the usual login prompt.
However, no matter what I enter, pressing the submit button redirects me right back to the login form, with no error message or anything.

It worked a day or two back just fine.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Thanks for downvote, much appreciated. Very constructive.

Comment: Try with different broswers.

Comment: Tried, didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, no idea what exactly fixed it.

1. Install php-mcrypt (I found that somewhere on google)
2. Clear all cookies
3. Set correct timezone and enable NTP (also from some forums)
4. Edit /etc/php/php.ini and enable mcrypt.so, and default timezone
5. Sacrifice one black goat

Now it works again :)

Comment: *Clear all cookies* → There's your solution.

Comment: actually that is quite certainly not the thing that solved it. After clearing cookies, the problem persisted...

Comment: That's strange, when a package is missing it normally throws an error. By the way why are you still using phpmyadmin? Use Adminer instead.

Comment: Well.. I've used it for years, never let me down until now. What's some reasons to switch to adminer?

Comment: Well, it's the updated version of phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin is no longer under active dev so it won't support newer db versions. Give it a shot, you won't be deceived.

Comment: @arielnmz Are you sure about the 'Not under active dev'. They are releasing updates almost weekly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly By active dev I mean adding new features and improvements. The last versions have been only bugfixes, [check this](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/news.php) and also read the description of Adminer [on their home](http://www.adminer.org/en/).

Comment: @arielnmz Dont get me wrong, I was just interested. I am certainly no phpMyAdmin evangelist, only use it when I have to. I have to say I dont think adminer is any better, and certainly not a better interface.

Comment: Well, of course that has to do with personal taste, personally I prefer adminer's ui, but again, it's about personal taste. I don't it's any better too, I just suggested its usage since phpmyadmin is being left aside for the good of adminer, speaking about development and support.

Comment: @arielnmz, Hmm, it does seem to be still actively being developed with new features.

Comment: @MightyPork, It's [the first line that solved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673074/632951) your problem.

Comment: @Pacerier NO! the first line does NOT solve the problem

Comment: for me this helped:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-with-hhvm-nginx-and-mariadb-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/

Answer (score 0):

All MySQL Server installs are configured with one userid called 'root' and the password is empty i.e. leave it blank.

So login with

```
Username = root
Password = (leave this blank)
```

**EDIT :**

When you created the user account you are using did you create the account in one domain or more than one domain.

In other words have you created userid@localhost but not userid@127.0.0.1 and userid@::1

If not try creating all 3.

Your Apache error log should give you a clue, if you are getting an error message with ::1 as the ip address, this is the problem.

Comment: I have a configured password and I can log in using the shell. This is not the problem.